# How would I/can I post a java web project from Netbeans to Sharepoint?

Tags: java, sharepoint, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I have a java web application that I am developing in Netbeans (and running through Tomcat). Is there any way to put this application on Sharepoint?

This is my first time doing this. I've read that to post the application to a tomcat server you just have to copy the .war file over, but I haven't been able to find an easy solution for Sharepoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharepoint isn't a Java Application Server. You'll have to use Tomcat (or another Java Application Server) to host your application.  If you need to interact with Sharepoint from your application, you'll have to use web services, a shared database or something else to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible out of the box. SharePoint only runs ASP.NET applications, not java projects.

You can deploy the solution to a Tomcat server and then use the Page Viewer Web Part to show external content.